# Scala - returning same type as passed as argument

Tags: scala, generics, code-reuse, return-type, generic-variance

Let's say I have a class M that classes A,B,C inherit:

```
abstract M
A extends M
B extends M
C extends M
```

And i should like to do something like this:

```
val a0:A = ...
val b0:B = ...
val c0:C = ...
val a1:A = transform[A](a0)
val b1:B = transform[B](b0)
val c1:C = transform[C](c0)
```

Where `transform` essentially does the same for each subtype and only differs in how the result object is constructed.

I have a hunch that's not possible and I need either copy code and create separate transform methods or resort to typecasting. Or is there a better way?

**EDIT**

Note that `def transform[T<:M](t:T):T` does not work. If we try to return an A,B or C, we will get the error messages below.

> Expression of type A does not conform to expected type T
>
> Expression of type B does not conform to expected type T
>
> Expression of type C does not conform to expected type T

**EDIT 2**
Perhaps some more detailed information on what I'm trying to do:

```
transform(m:M) = {
    val P = Property P computed from m
    m match {
        case a:A => construct and return new A from a with property P
        case b:B => construct and return new B from b with property P
        case c:C => construct and return new C from c with property P
        case _ => error
    }
}
```

If I do it like that, then I need casts:

```
val a1:A = transform(a0).asInstanceOf[A]
val b1:B = transform(b0).asInstanceOf[B]
val c1:C = transform(c0).asInstanceOf[C]
```

which I should like to eliminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of `transform`. If it's clear to the compiler that `transform` preserves the type then @Dimitry's answer works.

If you need less obvious (to the compiler) relationships between types then the usual way is the typeclass pattern.

```
trait Transformer[T] {
  def transform(t: T) : T
}

def transform[T: Transformer](t: T) = implicitly[Transformer[T]].transform(t)

implicit object ATransformer extends Transformer[A] {
  def transform(a: A): A = ...
}
implicit object BTransformer extends Transformer[B] {
  def transform(b: B): B = ...
}
```

Then you can implement the specific transforms for `A`/`B`/`C` in the specific objects, and the compiler will only allow you to call `transform` if you have a suitable `Transformer` in implicit scope.

Comment: Good addition, but User1291 told, that my solution don't work for him.. Any idea?

Comment: Interesting ... what's the advantage of this over simply overloading the transform method?

Comment: @Dimitry yes, if you are constructing your own A/B/C then you need the typeclass pattern like I've suggested and that should work. @User1291 The advantage is that this can be used if the method that calls `transform` is itself generic (you just include the typeclass constraint `[T: Transformer]`).

Answer (score 3):

That's quite easy:

```
class M
class A extends M
class B extends M

def transform[T <: M](obj: T): T = {
    obj
}

val a0:A = new A
val a1:A = transform(a0)
val b0:B = new B
val b1:B = transform(b0)
```

Comment: Perhaps I've hit my head, but doesn't `T >: M` mean that T is a superclass of M - any superclass of M - which is kind of the wrong direction in the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: Sory, made a misprinting. Edited my answer, try this code

Comment: I had tried that before I asked here. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work (see edit of the question).

Comment: I had tried. If it does work for you, then I guess my match on m (see 2nd edit above) simply isn't "obvious" enough - to put it in @Imm's words - to the compiler for it to work in my case.